# Passing PHP variables to JSON

Tags: php, json

Im new to JSON sintax and I need help to pass some results I've pulled via php from a database, to a JSON code. Here's the code:

```
<?php
        $id_num = urldecode (intval($_REQUEST['id_cod']));
        $rs = $lista->noticias_testa(1,$id_num);
        $result = mysql_num_rows($rs);

        $rs = $lista->noticiaAll($id_num);
        $result = mysql_num_rows($rs);

        $audio = "files/audios/".mysql_result($rs,0,"audio");
        $title_audio = mysql_result($rs,0,"title_audio");
    ?>
```

And this JSON to fill a playlist for my mp3 player

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function(){

        new jPlayerPlaylist({
            jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
            cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
        }, [
            {
                title:"place to put php variable $title_audio",
                mp3:"path to the music.mp3",                   
            },
        ]);
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

I want to pass the php variable **"$audio"** to the JSON **"mp3 path"** and **title**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How exactly are you doing this? You could just create the JSON object with PHP and return it to JavaScript.

Comment: Are you sure you mean json and not just javascript?

Comment: Both the php code and the javascript are on the same file. I'm thinking to simply concatenate the php variable inside the javascript

`title:"+<?php echo mysql_result($rs,$i,"descricao_audio");?>+"</div>"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If those two bits of code live within the same .php file, that's pretty straight forward, just go in the javascript part and echo the PHP variables, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){

    new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
    }, [
        {
            title:""+<?php echo $title_audio; ?>+"",
            mp3:""+<?php echo $audio; ?>+"",                   
        },
    ]);
});
//]]>
```

**Hint:** you could use a even shorter syntax, like:

```
{ 
    title:""+ <?=$title_audio ?> +"",
    mp3:""+ <?=$audio ?> +"",                 
},
```

Comment: Unsafe answer!!! If `$audio` and `$title_audio` are user supplied and come from a database you're vulnerable to XSS. Go to http://stackoverflow.com/a/28078737/438563 instead.

Comment: This should produce syntax errors in Javascript.

Comment: marcio: Yes if that data was provided by user, sure he would escape them first.... and deceze: i don't think so , cause the php is processed (server side) before the JavaScript, so when the JavaScript starts it would be only normal strings out there...will verify that

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what are doing but i think that you need [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

It will make your php object/array as json string.

```
<?php
$json = array('audio' => $audio,
              'title_audio' => $title_audio);

$json = json_encode($json);
?>
```

Then, you can output it as html/javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">';
    var myObject = <?php echo $json; ?>;
</script>
```

Now you can access your data in javascript

```
myObject.audio                 // will contain your audio file
myObject.title_audio           // will contain your number of tracks
```

Comment: JSON echoed into Javascript source code will be an object literal; `JSON.parse` expects a string. You don't need to `JSON.parse` an object literal at all, just `var myObject = <?php echo $json; ?>;` will do just fine.

Comment: tnx for notice, i was posting in hurry.